# Sharepoint commands not available in my computer's Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmdlets

I am working on a project at my job with Sharepoint 2013 On-premises, and recently I discovered that there are multiple benefits by using Powershell to perform different tasks with the site.

However, my problem is that when I check the commands available in my system with this cmdlet ***Get-Command -noun SP**** there aren't any cmdlets for Sharepoint available.

I've tried a couple of SP cmdlets and the message I receive is this one:

> The term 'SPcmdlet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

I let you some information describing a little bit more the environment:

```
Sharepoint version: 2013

Development computer OS: Windows 7 SP1

Powershell version: 2.0

Sharepoint privileges: Site-Owner (Not SiteCollection administrator)
```

I just need to verify what steps can I follow to can use the SP cmdlets in my project!

Best Regards

Comment: is SharePoint installed on your windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use the SharePoint Management Shell, or you can run PowerShell as Administrator and fire this line:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

If you have the right access, it will then allow you to run SharePoint cmdlets from then on.

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm getting this error message when I try to run that line:  Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
At line:1 char:13
+ Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell:String) [Add-P
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand